# Erro ao tentar exportar uma constante no react

Tags: react, redux

Criei esse reducer:

```
const funcionarioReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_FUNCIONARIO':
        return state.concat([action.data]);
      default:
        return state;
    }
}
export default funcionarioReducer;
```

Tento importar ele no index.js para criar uma store:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { funcionarioReducer } from './reducers/funcionarioReducer';
const store = createStore(funcionarioReducer);


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Porém quando eu rodo o projeto eu recebo:

> Attempted import error: 'funcionarioReducer' is not exported from
>   './reducers/funcionarioReducer'.

Estou estudando como base [este tutorial](https://codeburst.io/redux-a-crud-example-abb834d763c9), pelo que percebi estou fazendo exatamente igual o que ele especifica, porém continuo recebendo esse erro.

Answer (score 0):

Estranho esse erro que você recebe.

De qualquer forma, acredito que a solução seja realizar um **default import** ao invés de um **named import**, já que você faz um **default export**. Para fazer isso, basta realizar o import do `funcionarioReducer` da seguinte maneira:

```
import funcionarioReducer from './reducers/funcionarioReducer';
```

Criei um [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/heuristic-herschel-q2ljk) com uma estrutura similar ao que você apresentou e funcionou com a alteração que eu citei.

Para saber mais sobre **default import** e **named import**, recomendo a seguinte [leitura](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36796281/4476479).